# how to increase the heap size while using the new eclipse ADT environment

Tags: android, windows-7

[image: Android Developer Tool environment]

i am new to new this working environment for android app development.
above i had mention the image with mark as red on the specific part so if any know how to the 
given number 742 to a larger one.because while working when it reached to its max the environment crash.Windows 7 is OS

the environment i am using for android  app development
and download from the site[ANDROID DEVELOPER OFFICIAL SITE](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

Edit the eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.100.v20080501.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.0.100.v20080428-1330
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Increase     -XX:MaxPermSize=512M to 1024M to increase the Heap size.

Answer (score 2):

At eclipse installation path find eclipse.ini file

And chnage :

-`Xmx1024m`